# Does everyone have device specific Bluetooth issues with Android, or just me?

Tags: android, bluetooth, connection

I have been working on a app to connect to a speaker dock, and send data back and forth via bluetooth.   On some devices my code works flawlessly.   Other devices it will work about 80% of the time, and on a third set of devices it works 50/50.

I am curious if I am doing something wrong, or if other Bluetooth developers have the same issue?   The firmware on the Dock side was originally written with iOS in mind, but modified so it does not have to do the iOS authorization piece if connected to from Android.   Could that be part of the problem?

I am basically using the template Bluetooth connection code shown here:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAClient

The only difference is that I open a Insecure socket for devices that support it (based on SDK level).

So my question is:   Are there a lot of developers struggling with getting consistent client connections via Bluetooth on Android, or just me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I found Bluetooth to be very quirkly on Android in general, and highly variable between manufacturers.

When something doesn't work the way you expect you should check b.android.com before spending a lot of time trying to figure it out - lots of the problems I encountered were already logged there.  I think that is good advice for Android in general.

And for all that people like to rag on Samsung, LG, etc., I actually found Google's Nexus devices to be the worst.  The good news is that Google commissioned an entirely new Bluetooth stack for AOSP which was released with 4.2.  Initially it was even worse than the stack it replaced (bluez), but became roughly usable with 4.2.2 and the fact that they spent the money on the new stack gives me some hope.

Comment: Its not only the s/w, its h/w as well..all vendors(LG,Moto,Samsung...) uses different BT chipsets and some of these issues are caused/seen in chipsets (connection/music streaming). As most of the vendors modify android code , bluetooth usability is seen different across devices